# The image of a locally constant function is coutable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^m$. A function $f: X\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be locally constant if, for every $x\in X$, there is $\epsilon_x>0$ such that, $f(y)=c_x$, for all $y\in B_{\epsilon_x}(x)\cap X$. Show that if $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is locally constant, then $f(X)$ is countable.

My attempt:

I proved that $f(X)=\bigcup\limits_{x\in X}\{c_x\}$, but I don't know how can I deduce that $f(X)$ is countable from the equality above. So, I tried to define an injective function $\varphi: f(X)\to \mathbb{N}$, by putting $\varphi(f(x))=N_x$, where $N_x=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon_x}\rfloor+1$, but It didn't work too. I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\{B_{\epsilon_x}(x):x\in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$, and $\Bbb R^m$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, so it has a countable subcover.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Gerschgorin: Excellent! You’re welcome!